# Delete text from a Google slides using API

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-slides-api

I' m trying to repetetive presentation with Google Slides starting from the events on Google Calendar using an API.

I was able to replace some text, but I'd like to delete all the text after the last text replacement.
I've tried with replacing all the remaining text with a blank space, but i exceeded the quota limit, so maybe it's easier to just delete it.

(I hope it's understandable even in my broken english).

I hope you'll help me-

This is the function i use to replace the text (and it works fine):

```
def text_replace(old: str, new: str, presentation_id: str, pages: list = []):
    slides_service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    slides_service.presentations().batchUpdate(
        body={
            "requests": [
                {
                    "replaceAllText": {
                        "containsText": {
                            "text": '{{' + old + '}}'
                        },
                        "replaceText": new,
                        "pageObjectIds": pages,
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        presentationId=presentation_id
    ).execute()
```

[this is one of the slides i want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5SUk.png)

In the slide there's a single text box, and i wanted to know if it was possible to delete automatically some text

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `but I'd like to delete all the text after the last text replacement.`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: So basically I’m trying to pull all the events from a Google calendar and put them in a presentation so that it can be played in a monitor, as a daily agenda. So I created a presentation on Google slide in which I replace the text, but not all text get replaced, and I want to eliminate the remaining text

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand `I created a presentation on Google slide in which I replace the text, but not all text get replaced, and I want to eliminate the remaining text`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Tbf I had to read my own comment twice to understand what I was trying to say, so it’s not a you problem. In my presentation I’ve written 10 events “placeholders” in the form ‘{{event1}}’, ‘{{event2}}’, etc. But if there are less than 10 events in my calendar, in the Google slides presentation the placeholders remain, and I was wondering if there’s a way to remove them not manually, I hope it’s clearer now, but I’m here if you have more questions. Thanks for helping btw

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I think that I understood your question. But, in this case, it is required to know your current script. So, I agree with the comment of Community Bot.